# Angularjs - identify response body is null

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

How can I identify that the response body I am getting is null when I am inside the 'success' callback of the $promise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 'data' parameter of the success callback holds the returned response body. Have you inspected what 'data' contains?

Success callback ->

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (data == null) {
        doStuff();
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes I did. It has $promise, $resolve objects and functions such as $delete, $get and etc.

Comment: How can I retrieve the fact that the body is null?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by doing data.toJSON() and there I will get an empty object when request body is null.

Thanks